# Does Tensorflow automaticaly use multiple CPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, c-api

I have programmed some code doing an inference with Tensorflow's C API (CPU only). It is running on a cluster node, where I have access to 24 CPUs and 1 GPU. I do not make use of the GPU as I will need to do the task CPU-only later on.

Somehow every time I call the Tensorflow-Code from the other program (OpenFOAM) Tensorflow seems to run on all CPUs parallelized. However I have not done anything to cause this behavior. Now I would like to know whether Tensorflow does this parallelization by default?

Greets and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are using tensorflow. But a typical TensorFlow training has an input pipeline which can be thought as an ETL process. Following are the main activities involved:

**Extract**: Read data from persistent storage

**Transform**: Use CPU cores to parse and perform preprocessing operations on the data such as image decompression, data augmentation transformations (such as random crop, flips, and color distortions), shuffling, and batching.

**Load**: Load the transformed data onto the accelerator device(s) (for example, GPU(s) or TPU(s)) that execute the machine learning model.

CPUs are generally used during the data transformation. During the transformation, the data input elements are preprocessed. To improve the performance of the pre-processing, it is parallelized across multiple CPU cores by default.

Tensorflow provides the tf.data API which offers the tf.data.Dataset.map transformation. To control the parallelism, the map provides the num_parallel_calls argument.

Read more on this from here: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Comment: Hi, thanks! I am using the C API and only doing inference, no training at all.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question. Moreover with the change from TF 1.x to 2.x configuration of physical resources has changed in ways that makes it difficult to discern whether it is necessary to do special configuration in order to make physical cpu/gpu resources available or not.